# PIC/assembly, copy and rotate 10-bits between registers

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, pic, bit

PIC18F252

In assembly:

From A/D conversion, I have a 10-bit result left- or right-adjusted, at result registers ADRESH and ADRESL.

What's a clever method to get these 10 bits into TMR0H from bit 5 through TMR0L bit 4?

More specifically, with two 11s at the front:

```
XXXX XXXX XX00 0000 ADRESH ADRESL => 
11XX XXXX XXXX 0000 TMR0H TMR0L
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tested...

```
bsf     STATUS, _C    ;Set Carry 
rrcf    ADRESH, f     ;Do 16 bit shift right of ADRES 
rrcf    ADRESL, f
bsf     STATUS, _C    ;Set Carry 
rrcf    ADRESH, w     ;Do high byte shift right
movwf   TMR0H         ;Copy WREG to destination 
rrcf    ADRESL, w     ;Do low byte shift right 
movwf   TMR0L         ;Copy WREG to destination
```

Read also datasheet how TMR0 is updated: **10.4 16-Bit Mode Timer Reads and
Writes**

Comment: Nice. Tested: works! (Except: Used MPLAB 8.92 with Debugger 'MPLAB SIM'. TMR0H not being updated in the watch-list, but I assume it must be a limitation/bug of the simulator(?))

Comment: @bretddog: yes could be a bug.